# connect a vb net windows application to sqlserver installed on another computer in a network

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

i created a vb.net windows application.i have two computers connected with network(LAN).The two computer names are AdminPc1 and AdminPc2.i installed the application and sqlexpress 2005 in  AdminPc1 and it works properly. now i installed the application in  AdminPc2 and try to connect the database in AdminPc1 and it gives a network error. my sqlserver name is AdminPc1\SqlExpress. i use the same name in the connection string on the second computer.i enabled tcp/ip and named pipes connection in sqlserver configuration manager.  am i did anything wrong? if not then how to solve the problem? please help me...thank you.

Comment: Your question is missing all the relevant details.  ConnectionString.  Firewall properly configured.  Any custom SQL Network settings.

Comment: thank you mr.Dan-o.. i checked the firewall property it is on. i make it off. and saw one tutorial about allowing remote connections. as per that i created new inbound rules for sqlserver and sqlbrowser for exception.and now it works fine...problem solved.. thank you for reminding of the firewall and your immideiate reply. i appericiate that sir.